# Como hacer que una grilla seleccione el primer registro si depende de otra grilla

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Tengo un modelo, de la forma:

```
public class A
{
   public ObservableCollection B col1;
}

Public Class B
{
   public int BA;
   public int BB;
   public ObservableCollection C;
}

public Class C
{
   public int CA;
   public int CB;
}
```

El primer DataGrid se llena con el contenido de A, que no es mas que una lista de elementos B.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GrillaA" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BA}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BB}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Y despues tengo otra grilla, que se llena con el contenido de la lista que contiene B (la lista de objetos C)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GrillaB" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.C, ElementName=GrillaA}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CA}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CB}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Todo esto anda perfecto.. salvo que debajo de cada grilla tengo unos textbox que se llenan con el contenido de la fila seleccionada en la grilla... 
Para el caso de la primer grilla, no tengo problema, se llenan a la perfeccion..

La pregunta es: cuando selecciono un item en la GrillaA, como hago para que se seleccione el primer elemento de la GrillaB, en un modelo MVVM, de tal forma que se llenen los campos que estan abajo de esa grilla?

---

**EDICION**

Dejo un ejemplo en git:

https://github.com/topcatarg/PruebaGrillasMVVM

y no, mas alla de la primer pantalla, en la segunda pantalla al seleccionar un item de la primer grilla, la segunda grilla no selecciona el primer item (porque la propiedad de seleccion se ejecuta dos veces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es añadir en tus grids la propiedad `SelectedIndex` con propiedades de tu View Model,tanto en GrillaA como GrillaB:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GrillaA" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Lista2}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedA,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="GrillaB" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Lista2}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedB,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Entonces en tu ViewModel añades las dos propiedades,y en el setter de la primera (que se ejecutara cuando cambie el indice seleccionado en `GrillaA`) podrás cambiar el índice de la otra grilla :

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _selectedA=-1;
    private int _selectedB=-1;
    public int SelectedA
    {
        get { return this._selectedA; }
        set
        {
            this._selectedA = value;
            this.SelectedB = 0;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int SelectedB
    {
        get { return this._selectedB; }
        set
        {
            this._selectedB = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }

    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es una posible solución, hay otras pero yo normalmente me decanto por esta.

---

**Editado**

Paso a exponer otra solución, ya que al usar una propiedad del `SelectedItem` del primer grid para cargar el `ItemsSource` del segundo, la primera solución propuesta no funcionaba correctamente.

Primero, hay que añadir en el binding del `ItemsSource` del gridB la propiedad de dependencia `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` a `true`,para que se nos notifique cuando se cambia el `ItemsSource`.  Después, simplemente nos subscribimos al evento `TargetUpdated` del gridB y ahi seleccionamos el primer índice. Ejemplo:

*XAML:*

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgListaB" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaB}"/>
<DataGrid x:Name="dgListaC" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.ListaC, ElementName=dgListaB,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="dgListaC_TargetUpdated"/>
```

*Manejador del evento:*

```
private void dgListaC_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    this.dgListaC.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: no me estaria andando.. esa propiedad tiene que implementar Inotify?

Comment: Si,debe implementar `inotifypropertychanged`. Mañana si no lo consigues edito con un ejemplo probado,esto fue de memoria :)

Comment: ahhh ya me parecia...

Comment: Ok.. agreguemos eso para el proximo novato.. e Igual estoy mirando porque la propiedad SelectedB se ejecuta dos veces.. y a veces queda con nada marcado, porque le  carga un -1 al indice (que se lo debe mandar la grilla)..

Comment: @gbianchi he editado la respuesta con algun fallo que tenía. He probado esta solución en un proyecto de prueba y a mi me funciona perfectamente, si tienes problemas me comentas :)